# Is there any shortcut or add-on for Firefox that would allow going back to previous view position (within the current page)?

Tags: firefox, browsing, keyboard-navigation

I'm kind of missing this feature which I use all the time in Visual Studio when browsing through the code, inside my browser (it's Ctrl+-). So how is such feature supposed to work in a browser?

The page is loaded and the top part of it is displayed. You use in-page navigation controls like scroll, page-up/down, home/end etc. The page-up/down have this nice property of reversibility, they are mutually dual, would I say. This "reverse motion" feature is missing for home, end and scroll.

### *Edit*: Example of workflow, where the described feature 'd be needed:

You hit the Home key to look back for information you saw previously (esp. on long pages), or you hit End key to come to end (where next chapter, See Also (on wikipedia) or other information of interest is located, as you expect), then you want to go back where you was reading previously. How? Or you can hit those keys by accident, not sure why, but sometimes I mistake Shift+Ctrl+End for simple Shift+End and there is no way back (other then rolling the page to look for where the selection starts).

Other (painful) case is searching in Firefox. You get focus to the search bar (by Ctrl+F for example) and start writing the word you'd like to find. Firefox immediately reacts by scrolling the main view to the first match to your (partial) input, possibly not finding the whole term, but the scoll position is already screwed on the last match, or match with a torso of your search query. Now how to get back?

Is there a solution? I haven't find any other then implementing it on my own (I'd use Alt+up), for which I don't have time now.

Comment: It isn't clear from the question what you want.  What *exactly* would you want to happen when you pressed alt-up?

Comment: Now I can tell you exactly. I'd like the view of the web page to return to previous scrolling state (mostly vertically). Building the database on each view change seems to be the trickier part, then just something like SetScrollPos(lastUsed) would be called on the command.

Comment: Do you mean the position where scrolling last stopped?  Usually when you scroll a webpage, you scroll bit by bit as you read it, so lots of short stops.  The last stop from my perspective would be just a little above where you are currently.  I think what you need in in-page bookmarking, where you can press a key to indicate a stop, and then alt-up would take you back there.

Comment: I feel, you understood what I want, but I can't agree with your assumption that the scrolling history contains _only_ short moves (steps). I'll try to give you a few examples...added them to the questing, for the comment would be too long.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question, maybe this addon can work for you:

Book Text Mark 1.1.1
by Roman Mironenko

Use context menu or Bookmarks menu to set mark lines within long pages. Navigate to marked pages and to the marked lines.

Highlight interesting sections of text, navigate between highlighted sections.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/book-text-mark/

Comment: Sadly that can't help me. I'd like to have an automatic _anchoring_ feature, as implied by the problem of view-loosing in-page search mechanism.